# PostgreSQL database does not exist error

Tags: postgresql

I am getting a "database does not exist error", even when the database exists:

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE Owino to OdooD;
```

> ERROR:  database "owino" does not exist

```
Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |    Access privileges

Owino   | dominus  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
postgres| postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres           +
        |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
        |          |          |             |             | orokon=CTc/postgres    +
        |          |          |             |             | powerbidev=CTc/postgres+
        |          |          |             |             | odoodev=CTc/postgres
```

Answer (score 10):

The database was created with double quotes, so the name is now case-sensitive and you are now stuck with the dreaded quoted identifiers. `"Owino"` is a different name than `Owino`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "Owino" to OdooD;
```

Depending on how you created the user, you might need to use the dreaded double quotes for the user name as well (`"OdooD"`).

I **highly** recommend to simply never use double quotes in SQL.

See the manual for more details:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score -3):

Dont use mixed case database names, there are several applications that will have problems with this

Owino is mixed case

The answer above imples that you created the database name using " ".

I have encountered this issue when I created a database name without " ", just using a mixed case name like MyDatabase

Comment: What does this add to the other answer?

Comment: The advice is good, but it is indeed not an answer to the problem presented.